# Groovy script: How to safeguard against possible memory leak or infinite loops

Tags: groovy

We intend to allow our clients to execute their own groovy scripts within our platform. They will be allowed to access only controlled methods but we have one concern.
Although we will take all possible care somewhere we might get into a risk of long running loops - resulting in memory leak or infinite loop which can affect our platform.
Is there any inherent way within groovy script to protect against such probability?

Comment: Why not just kill the script after a give time? A loop might be finite per se, but still doesn't finish this year or next.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent loops and all dangerous syntax constructs with a [SecureASTCustomizer](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/customizers/SecureASTCustomizer.html).

Nice article [here](http://melix.github.io/blog/2015/03/sandboxing.html).

If you can restrict your DSL (the code your client can run) so that it can only invoke your methods on your object(s), it's up to you to guarantee memory cannot leak or be abused in any way.

1. Build your `GroovyShell` by passing it a custom `CompilerConfiguration`
2. Build your custom `CompilerConfiguration` with a custom `SecureASTCustomizer` using method `addCompilationCustomizers(...)`
3. You probably want to get all function calls in your DSL to go through a custom class of yours. For that, have your shell parse the script, cast the script as a `DelegatingScript` and pass it your object:

   ```
   DemoDSLHelper delegate = new DemoDSLHelper(); // Your custom class with custom methods you want to expose in the DSL
   GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(createCompilerConfiguration());
   Script script = shell.parse(scriptText);
   ((DelegatingScript)script).setDelegate(delegate);
   Object result = script.run();
   ```
4. Run that in a separate JVM, so that you can enforce limits on the process with OS-dependent primitives for that (containerization, etc), or simply kill it if it fails to respect your rules (duration, resources consumption, etc). If it must run within a JVM that does other things, at the very least you'll need to be extremely restrictive in what you accept in the DSL.

And [here a gist](https://gist.github.com/hogmoru/291cf01a1794a7d98454dbb85675512c) with complete runnable example.

Comment: Thanks for the gist Hugues. SecureASTCustomizer looks useful. The article is also good.